# IronPython TypeError exception has no traceback

Tags: python, exception, ironpython, traceback

In my code I am having a `TypeError` exception that is crashing my code. In this one particular program (I created a test file to reproduce the error and couldn't) the traceback only says `TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable` with no information about where it was occuring. I tried creating my own exception before the function call that this must be happening in by `1[0]` and got the same problem. When I try causing a different kind of exception by `foo_that_doesn't_exist()` I get a proper traceback with where the error occurred.  I'm running the IronPython interpreter and because of some dependencies on C# code I can't test with CPython.

EDIT: I tracked down the problem in my own code, and then found a way to reproduce it. The problem can be recreated with:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    try:
        1[0]
    except:
        raise
except:
    traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Which returns nothing while:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:

    1[0]
except:
    traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

returns

```
File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    1[0]
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but hard to know without some way to reproduce it. Can you open an issue (https://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) and attach a repro if you find one?

Comment: I tracked it down, and was finally able to reproduce it. I updated my question and will open an issue also.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you add `traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])` (inside `except:` block)? And `import sys, traceback`.

Comment: @Dunno Will do. See the official report at https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/35204

Comment: @Dunno See edit above.